# How can I open thunar so that it selects specific file?

Tags: thunar

Like in title. On Windows, I can do this:

```
explorer /select,"C:\folder\file.txt"
```

which will result in opening of `explorer.exe`, that will immediately open `C:\folder` and select `file.txt`.

I believe ROX had this functionality too.

Can I do the same with thunar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a little digging, I discovered this is possible using D-Bus:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dbus
import os
import sys
import urlparse
import urllib


bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object('org.xfce.Thunar', '/org/xfce/FileManager')
iface = dbus.Interface(obj, 'org.xfce.FileManager')

_thunar_display_folder = iface.get_dbus_method('DisplayFolder')
_thunar_display_folder_and_select = iface.get_dbus_method('DisplayFolderAndSelect')


def display_folder(uri, display='', startup_id=''):
    _thunar_display_folder(uri, display, startup_id)


def display_folder_and_select(uri, filename, display='', startup_id=''):
    _thunar_display_folder_and_select(uri, filename, display, startup_id)


def path_to_url(path):
    return urlparse.urljoin('file:', urllib.pathname2url(path))


def url_to_path(url):
    return urlparse.urlparse(url).path


def main(args):
    path = args[1]  # May be a path (from cmdline) or a file:// URL (from OS)
    path = url_to_path(path)
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    url = path_to_url(path)

    if os.path.isfile(path):
        dirname = os.path.dirname(url)
        filename = os.path.basename(url)
        display_folder_and_select(dirname, filename)
    else:
        display_folder(url)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(sys.argv)
```

Execute with:

```
$ ./thunar-open-file.py /home/user/myfile.txt
```

And it will still open a folder, if you pass that:

```
$ ./thunar-open-file.py /home/user/
```

[image: screencast for hardcore proof]

Comment: Unfortunately, some applications (looking at you, Chrome) don't even send the full file path. They actually send the path to the parent folder =/

Comment: In the new Thunar version (shipped with xfce 4.14), you can just send the path to a file and it will select that file on opening.

Answer (score 10):

Building upon answer from `theY4Kman`, this is how to do it without Python:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.xfce.Thunar /org/xfce/FileManager org.xfce.FileManager.DisplayFolderAndSelect string:"/home/user/Downloads" string:"File.txt" string:"" string:""
```

The only caveat is that you need to separate folder path and file name.

Comment: thanks! note that the `org.xfce.FileManager.DisplayFolderAndSelect` is XFCE-specific, but today a more portable method is available: ```dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.freedesktop.FileManager1 /org/freedesktop/FileManager1 org.freedesktop.FileManager1.ShowItems array:string:"file:///path/to/file_to_focus" string:""``` - it works on XFCE4 (tested on Xubuntu 20.04) and GNOME (tested on Ubuntu 20.04) and KDE (tested on Kubuntu 20.04) and Budgie (tested on Ubuntu Budgie 20.04) and Mate (tested on Ubuntu Mate 20.04).  - notably, it does *NOT* work on LXQt (tested on Lubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 3):

With thunar's built-in command line switches, you can't. If you see `man thunar`, you'll figure that you could only open a folder that way, but you won't be able to preselect a file in it.

Does it mean that you can't do it at all?

Fortunately not, but you'll need help from external programs. An example that accomplishes this using **xdotool** to send `ctrl+s` and type in `filename` (which effectively is going to select it):

```
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
[ -z "$file" ]; then
    echo 'No file selected' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if [[ ! $(command -v thunar) ]]; then
    echo 'Thunar is not installed' 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    thunar "$file" &
else
    if [ ! -f "$file" ]; then
        echo 'File does not exist' 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    if [[ ! $(command -v xdotool) ]]; then
        echo 'Xdotool is not installed' 1>&2
        exit 1
    fi

    set -e #exit on any error
    thunar "$(dirname "$file")" &
    window_id=`xdotool search --sync --onlyvisible --class 'Thunar' | head -n1`
    xdotool key --clearmodifiers 'ctrl+s'
    xdotool type "$(basename "$file")"
    xdotool key Return
fi
```

Usage: `script /path/to/file-or-folder`

There are two caveats:

1. You'll notice slight lag due to `xdotool --sync`, but I believe it's acceptable.
2. This won't work with files hidden in thunar for any reason, such as dotfiles.